# Can someone explain what this function is?

Tags: php, function

I have the following function that the professor has made available. It has something to do with logging on, but I am not sure why it seems that I can only get the "Invalid username/password" message, and no success, even when I KNOW there is a user by the name I am using in the db.....

```
function post_index($params) {
$username = safeParam($_REQUEST, 'username', false);
$password = safeParam($_REQUEST, 'password', false);
if (isValidUser($username, $password)) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    if (isset($_SESSION['redirect'])) {
        $redirect = $_SESSION['redirect'];
        redirect($redirect);
        exit();
    }
    redirectRelative("index");
} else {
// @formatter:off
renderTemplate(
    "views/login_form.inc",
    array(
        'title' => 'Login',
        'errors' => array("Invalid username/password"),
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    )
);
// @formatter:on
}
```

Comment: so, you've got a whole bunch of other functions that we don't know what they do. Your db schema is unknown and we're supposed to figure out what's wrong? 9 times out of 10, it's the password column's length that's not long enough to accomodate the hash (if it's hashed). No idea on how to provide a solution for this. If you don't know, same here. Nor, do we know if the session was started.

Answer (score 0):

The function proccess a request, sanitaze and redirect the user to the index or to the login if the process fails, you always get the error because the function isValidUser always return false.

I suggests you check some tutorials of how to do a login